# perl client-to-server file sending and vice versa using sockets

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp, client-server

I'm a newbie in stackoverflow and in perl IO::Socket sockets programming. 
I have a problem with my project. 
I have a TCP client and server script where the client can send file to the server. 
The server side creates a directory where it stores received files.
It can display the files inside the directory.
It can also read files(txt) or delete files.

The problem is the client side...
Is it possible for the server to also send a file to a client?
and is it also possible for the client to delete files from the server?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes and no.

When you talk about creating TCP client and server all that you have is two pipes - sort of 2-wire copper telephone line. As you can imagine, you can transmit a lot of things over the telephone, and you can even implement file transfer protocol over that. However, there is nobody here to help you actually implement such protocol. Doing it could be quite complicated - just look at protocols like FTP, HTTP, SMB, NFS, SCP/SSH. All these protocols can talk over TCP and send files. But they are not very simple.

That said, you can probably implement very simple subset of functionality necessary to transmit a file, but it will be very simplistic. If your project is not purely theoretical, you may find it easier to use some existing file transfer protocol instead or in addition to your new service.

Also, when you talk about deleting a file, the very first consideration should be security. If other side asks you to delete some file, how could you trust that it is legitimate connection? What if somebody is trying to exploit your service and either maliciously remove some critical files, or just trying to hack into your server by deleting say `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`? In other words, it extremely complicated and fragile topic, and the very first rule is to never trust or assume anything about another party, much like talking to stranger over telephone.